# How to change the labels of hover info in Plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

In a chart I render using Plotly.js, I define titles for each axis.  When mouse hovering the items within the chart, a popup is shown, but the "labels" shown do not use the titles I had defined.

For example, the default value for the x axis is `x`.  I defined `hellox` as title and that value is show in the chart, but not when mouse hovering a value (`x` is still shown).

See a live example here of what I mean: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoGQvx

I've been looking a the documentation and I didn't find anything so far that did exactly what I wanted: simply change the labels in the popup.

Comment: I don't believe there is an option for this but it's a good idea if you want to submit it as an issue here https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js :)

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2618

Answer (score 1):

Also the question is quite old, I would like to write a solution I came up when facing the same problem. I did define a var text array for hover info which I filled with the labels for x, y and z values. Please have a look at the following fiddle where I use a heatmap plot for demonstration (this is what I am using in my project, but it can be easily adapted for your chart option): http://jsfiddle.net/zLc5y63g/

This is the html code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<body>
<br><br>
<!-- Source and on-click event for plotly.js -->
<div id="plotly_chart" style="width: 90%; height: 270px"></div>
```

And this the JavaScript:

```
var zValues = [[1, 20, 30], [20, 1, 60], [30, 60, 1]];
var yValues = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
var xValues = ['condition1', 'condition2', 'condition3'];

var config = {
  displaylogo: false
};
      
// fill in 'text' array for hover
var text = zValues.map (function(zValues, i) { 
  return zValues.map (function (value, j) {
    return ` ID: ${yValues[i]}<br> Condition: ${xValues[j]}<br> Value: ${value.toFixed(2)} `
  });
});

Plotly.newPlot('plotly_chart', [
  {
    x: xValues, 
    y: yValues, 
    z: zValues, 
    text: text, 
    hoverinfo: 'text', 
    hoverlabel: { bgcolor: '#41454c' }, 
    type: 'heatmap', 
    colorscale: 'Viridis',
   }
 ], config );
```

Maybe this is still useful.